# How to run Applescript Photoshop Automate Batch of an Action

Tags: applescript, photoshop

I am trying to make an Applescript that will launch Photoshop and call the Automate Batch function to run a specific Action.  I have zero experience doing this and have only gotten snippets of code from my searching.  I was wondering if someone could help me on this.. in particular if it is at all possible to pass a source folder to the batch call and then how to make the Batch call.

In particular, I am having issues trying to figure out how to:

1. Pass the source folder into the Batch Options
2. Call a specific Action in the Batch_Options from my Photoshop
3. Run the batch call with these options

I've updated with the latest code that is partially there...

```
tell application "Finder"
    set sourceFolder to "Macintosh HD:Users:Joe:Desktop:Temp:" as alias
    set folderList to every item of folder sourceFolder as alias list

    do shell script "echo File Names are: " & folderList
end tell

tell application "Adobe Photoshop CC 2018"
    set action_set_name to "Save as Photoshop PDF"
    activate
    try
        set Batch_Options to {class:batch options, destination:save and close, error file:Error_File, file naming:{document name lower, extension lower}, macintosh compatible:true, override open:false, override save:true, suppress open:true, suppressprofile:true, unix compatible:true, windows compatible:true}
        batch "Save" from files folderList from action_set_name with options Batch_Options
    end try
end tell
```

output:

"File Names are: Macintosh HD:Users:Joe:Desktop:Temp:Creature01_CO_v003.psdMacintosh HD:Users:Joe:Desktop:Temp:SecretLaboratory.psd"

Photoshop opens, and then nothing happens...

Comment: In my experience with AppleScript, I found it better to limit the code into keystrokes: tab, enter, etc. It's not readable *at all*, but usually performs better

Comment: Thats nice, but not what I am trying to accomplish here

Comment: @GalAbra Readability is at the bottom of reasons why that method (and encouraging it) is only ever last resort, and often not even then. You may have lucked out or had limited cases to use such scripts in practice, but they are notoriously fragile, temperamental, slow, inconvenient, and many other adjectives that also describe Brexit.  It's the Brexit of AppleScripting.

Comment: @CJK Loved you comment. Unfortunately the problem is the AS doesn't provide enough documentation in order to write a stable code

Comment: @GalAbra The best advice I can give is to find examples online, experiment, break some scripts, fix them again, and re-write them in a different way.  That's basically how you learn any scripting or programming language.  There are some [decent online PDFs](http://ommolketab.ir/aaf-lib/95rg841imiupo1k56qexitvd5nfuou.pdf) too. It's all trial by error until it one day isn't.

Comment: Any particular reasons why you want to go with AppleScript? JavaScript has so much more examples and documented much better

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy I'd love to know how to do this via javascript, but I find majority of the time I can't find relevant calls/info to do that... whereas Applescript I can.  Care to help direct me?

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work in the Automator:

```
    tell application "Finder"
        set sourceFolder to "Macintosh HD:Users:Joe:Desktop:Temp:" as alias
        set folderList to every item of folder sourceFolder as alias list
        do shell script "echo File Names are: " & folderList

        #Alias list needs to be converted to a string for it to work in Photoshop batch call
        set FileNames to {}
        repeat with i from 1 to the count of folderList
            set current_file to item i of folderList
            copy current_file as text to the end of FileNames
        end repeat

        #Setup error log
        set err_log to (sourceFolder as string) & "Error_Log.txt"
        if not (exists file err_log) then
            make new file at sourceFolder with properties {name:"Error_Log.txt"}
        end if
    end tell

    tell application "Adobe Photoshop CC 2018"
        set action_set_name to "SetA"
        activate
        set Batch_Options to {class:batch options, destination:save and close, error file:err_log, file naming:{document name lower, extension lower}, macintosh compatible:true, override open:false, override save:true, suppress open:true, suppressprofile:true, unix compatible:true, windows compatible:true}
        #First arg is the Action Name, second is the list of files, third is the Action Set Name
        batch "ActionA" from files FileNames from "SetA" with options Batch_Options
    end tell
```